Log4j2 Not write to log after I exported to .jar
I have a log4j2.xml which works correctly, until I export the project. The basePath in this case configured manually. So the log file location is correct even after export. After the exporting, just the console work. Export works with the required JAR files: slf4j-api-2.0.12.jar, log4j-core-2.22.1.jar, log4j-api-2.22.1.jar. etc...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">C:\Temp\printer\logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="emailFile" fileName="${basePath}\emails.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <File name="errorFile" fileName="${basePath}\errors.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <File name="infoFile" fileName="${basePath}\information.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="generalLog" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="infoFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="errorFile" level="error"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="emailLog" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="emailFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

I checked the paths, jar files, but everything was fine.
I changed everywhere in the xml: <File name="emailFile" fileName="${basePath}\emails.log"> to <File name="emailFile" fileName="C:\Temp\printer\logs\emails.log">
I saw that someone had the same question, but they had a problem with the path, but this problem does not exist in this case.

If the config file is finalised you should put it into the jar. So it should start at src/main/resources

Unfortunately, not finalised.

Meaning you want/need to leave it outside the jar?

Not needed, but the xml file is founded, becasuse if I remove the .xml file, the code throw Exception.

Not needed doesn't make sense. You either want it inside or outside the jar - which is it?

I want to inside it.

Well I just told you where to put it. With your config, using: import org.slf4j.Logger;import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;public class App {static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("emailLog");public static void main(String[] args) {if (args.length > 0) {if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {log.info("Value for arg was {}", args[0]);}if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {log.debug("Value for arg was {}", args[0]);}}}} Creates files (changed base) ../logs/ ../logs/emails.log ../logs/information.log ../logs/errors.log Incidentally that's the correct was to do logging of any major framework (log4j2 here)

Does not write out anything.

jar tf thejar.jar | findstr "log4j2.xml" says what?

Return with: log4j2.xml

How are you running the jar?

java -jar thejar.jar

log4j-slf4j-impl is what I'm using. Use that instead of the current slf4j you're using

Just? Nothing else? slf4j-api-2.0.12.jar, log4j-core-2.22.1.jar, log4j-api-2.22.1.jar.

so it doesn't work in the project anymore.

log4j-api, log4j-core, log4j-slf4j-impl Is your code in a public repository?

@g00se: SLF4J 2 requires log4j-slf4j2-impl instead of log4j-slf4j-impl.
@KrisztoferTörök: what does "export to .jar" mean? What are you using to create the JAR? Creating uber-JARs can break a lot of things.

Vs Code -> Explorer -> Java Project -> Export jar... -> With main -> All of determine elements. And yes in a public repository.

And yes in a public repository If you post a link I'll take a look. @PiotrP.Karwasz that makes a lot of sense yet it still works for me actually
